# Can I get the user email within a Velocity template of AWS Amplify?

Tags: aws-amplify, velocity, aws-appsync

When I query a resolver in my GraphQL API, in which I have added a $util.error($ctx) to return the context object, I get the following result (removed unnecessary values).

```json
{
  "data": {
    "listXData": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": {
        "arguments": {},
        "args": {},
        "info": {
          "fieldName": "listXData",
          "variables": {},
          "parentTypeName": "Query",
          "selectionSetList": [
            "items",
            "items/id",
            "items/createdAt",
            "items/updatedAt",
            "nextToken"
          ],
          "selectionSetGraphQL": "{\n  items {\n    id\n    createdAt\n    updatedAt\n  }\n  nextToken\n}"
        },
        "request": {...},
        "identity": {
          "sub": "",
          "issuer": "",
          "username": "013fe9d2-95f7-4885-83ec-b7e2e0a1423f",
          "sourceIp": "",
          "claims": {
            "origin_jti": "",
            "sub": "",
            "event_id": "",
            "token_use": "",
            "scope": "",
            "auth_time": ,
            "iss": "",
            "exp": ,
            "iat": ,
            "jti": "",
            "client_id": "",
            "username": "013fe9d2-95f7-4885-83ec-b7e2e0a1423f"
          },
          "defaultAuthStrategy": "ALLOW"
        },
        "stash": {},
        "source": null,
        "result": {
          "items": [],
          "scannedCount": 0,
          "nextToken": null
        },
        "error": null,
        "prev": {
          "result": {}
        }
      },
      "errorType": null,
      "data": null,
      "errorInfo": null,
      "path": [
        "listXData"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": "GraphQL request"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the username is an ID, however I would prefer to (also) have the email. Is it possible to get the user email (within the Velocity template)?

Let me know if I need to add more details or if my question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, it seems that it is not possible to do this purely by vtl.

I have implemented it using a lambda function, as follow:

Lambda function (node):

```js
/* Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT
    ENV
    REGION
Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT */

const aws = require('aws-sdk')

const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
  apiVersion: '2016-04-18',
  region: 'eu-west-1'
})

exports.handler = async (context, event, callback) => {
  if (!context.identity?.username) {
    callback('Not signed in')
  }
  const params = {
    'AccessToken': context.request.headers.authorization
  }
  const result = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.getUser(params).promise()
  const email = result.UserAttributes.find(attribute => attribute.Name === 'email')
  callback(null, JSON.stringify({ email }))
}
```

CustomResources.json

```json
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "An auto-generated nested stack.",
  "Metadata": {...},
  "Parameters": {...},
  "Resources": {
    "GetEmailLambdaDataSourceRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "RoleName": {
          "Fn::If": [
            "HasEnvironmentParameter",
            {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "-",
                [
                  "GetEmail17ec",
                  {
                    "Ref": "GetAttGraphQLAPIApiId"
                  },
                  {
                    "Ref": "env"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            },
            {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "-",
                [
                  "GetEmail17ec",
                  {
                    "Ref": "GetAttGraphQLAPIApiId"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "appsync.amazonaws.com"
              },
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Policies": [
          {
            "PolicyName": "InvokeLambdaFunction",
            "PolicyDocument": {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "lambda:InvokeFunction"
                  ],
                  "Resource": {
                    "Fn::If": [
                      "HasEnvironmentParameter",
                      {
                        "Fn::Sub": [
                          "arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:GetEmail-${env}",
                          {
                            "env": {
                              "Ref": "env"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "Fn::Sub": [
                          "arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:GetEmail",
                          {}
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "GetEmailLambdaDataSource": {
      "Type": "AWS::AppSync::DataSource",
      "Properties": {
        "ApiId": {
          "Ref": "AppSyncApiId"
        },
        "Name": "GetEmailLambdaDataSource",
        "Type": "AWS_LAMBDA",
        "ServiceRoleArn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "GetEmailLambdaDataSourceRole",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "LambdaConfig": {
          "LambdaFunctionArn": {
            "Fn::If": [
              "HasEnvironmentParameter",
              {
                "Fn::Sub": [
                  "arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:GetEmail-${env}",
                  {
                    "env": {
                      "Ref": "env"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "Fn::Sub": [
                  "arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:GetEmail",
                  {}
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "DependsOn": "GetEmailLambdaDataSourceRole"
    },
    "InvokeGetEmailLambdaDataSource": {
      "Type": "AWS::AppSync::FunctionConfiguration",
      "Properties": {
        "ApiId": {
          "Ref": "AppSyncApiId"
        },
        "Name": "InvokeGetEmailLambdaDataSource",
        "DataSourceName": "GetEmailLambdaDataSource",
        "FunctionVersion": "2018-05-29",
        "RequestMappingTemplateS3Location": {
          "Fn::Sub": [
            "s3://${S3DeploymentBucket}/${S3DeploymentRootKey}/pipelineFunctions/${ResolverFileName}",
            {
              "S3DeploymentBucket": {
                "Ref": "S3DeploymentBucket"
              },
              "S3DeploymentRootKey": {
                "Ref": "S3DeploymentRootKey"
              },
              "ResolverFileName": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                  ".",
                  [
                    "InvokeGetEmailLambdaDataSource",
                    "req",
                    "vtl"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "ResponseMappingTemplateS3Location": {
          "Fn::Sub": [
            "s3://${S3DeploymentBucket}/${S3DeploymentRootKey}/pipelineFunctions/${ResolverFileName}",
            {
              "S3DeploymentBucket": {
                "Ref": "S3DeploymentBucket"
              },
              "S3DeploymentRootKey": {
                "Ref": "S3DeploymentRootKey"
              },
              "ResolverFileName": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                  ".",
                  [
                    "InvokeGetEmailLambdaDataSource",
                    "res",
                    "vtl"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "DependsOn": "GetEmailLambdaDataSource"
    },                
    "IsOrganizationMember": {
      "Type": "AWS::AppSync::FunctionConfiguration",
      "Properties": {
        "FunctionVersion": "2018-05-29",
        "ApiId": {
          "Ref": "AppSyncApiId"
        },
        "Name": "IsOrganizationMember",
        "DataSourceName": "PermissionsPerOrganizationTable",
        "RequestMappingTemplateS3Location": {
          "Fn::Sub": [
            "s3://${S3DeploymentBucket}/${S3DeploymentRootKey}/resolvers/Query.isOrganizationMember.req.vtl",
            {
              "S3DeploymentBucket": {
                "Ref": "S3DeploymentBucket"
              },
              "S3DeploymentRootKey": {
                "Ref": "S3DeploymentRootKey"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "ResponseMappingTemplateS3Location": {
          "Fn::Sub": [
            "s3://${S3DeploymentBucket}/${S3DeploymentRootKey}/resolvers/Query.isOrganizationMember.res.vtl",
            {
              "S3DeploymentBucket": {
                "Ref": "S3DeploymentBucket"
              },
              "S3DeploymentRootKey": {
                "Ref": "S3DeploymentRootKey"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "OrganizationAccessPipeline": {
      "Type": "AWS::AppSync::Resolver",
      "Properties": {
        "ApiId": {
          "Ref": "AppSyncApiId"
        },
        "TypeName": "Query",
        "Kind": "PIPELINE",
        "FieldName": "listXData",
        "PipelineConfig": {
          "Functions": [
            {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "InvokeGetEmailLambdaDataSource",
                "FunctionId"
              ]
            },
            {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "IsOrganizationMember",
                "FunctionId"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "RequestMappingTemplate": "{}",
        "ResponseMappingTemplate": "$util.toJson($ctx.result)"
      }
    }
  },
  "Conditions": {...},
  "Outputs": {...}
}
```

The lambda is created with the CLI and IsOrganizationMember is a regular VTL which has the user email in the `$context.prev.result`.

Answer (score 1):

The [identity context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html#aws-appsync-resolver-context-reference-identity) only returns back the Cognito username for the user pool.  You will need to setup [pipeline functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/pipeline-resolvers.html) to perform additional queries to get your user information. [Here is one intro to setting them up.](https://dev.to/dagasatvik10/add-pipeline-resolvers-in-aws-amplify-43ae)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Kinda hoped I didn't have to use a lambda in my pipeline there. Guess there is no other way ‍♂️.. I'm going to look into this.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on your setup. In mine, I have a Dyanmodb user table that works in concert with Cognito ( saves the Cognito usernames/user info).  So I use a pipeline resolver to query the user table on the Cognito username. In that case, I am not using a lambda, but a 'native' Appsync resolver that queries dynamodb.

Comment: Does it sync? The user table in DynamoDB with Cognito. Of are there no mutations happening on the user info?

Comment: I use the post confirmation lambda trigger to add the user to the dynamodb database. At that point, I pretty much manage my user from there. Any updates to user data are done through a lambda, at which point you can save to both Cognito and dynamo.